# What happens if Jace, Telepath Unbound is returned to your hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So if [Jace, Telepath Unbound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Telepath%20Unbound) is returned to your hand, does it turn back into [Jace, Vryn's Prodigy](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Vryn%27s%20Prodigy) to be recast or does it in effect go to your graveyard because Jace, Telepath Unbound cant be recast?

Answer (score 9):

When it enters a new zone, it resets back to its default characteristics. Namely as a creature card. So, you can then recast it as Jace, Vryn's Prodigy.

This is based on two rulings on Gatherer:

> While a double-faced card isn’t on the battlefield, consider only the characteristics of its front face.
>
> A double-faced card enters the battlefield with its front face up by default, unless a spell or ability instructs you to put it onto the battlefield transformed, in which case it enters with its back face up.

Comment: Hey man thanks. I know it was probably a dumb question but it came up in a game yesterday and I couldn't give a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Teichild If someone answers the question to your satisfaction, accept it by clicking on the green check mark. You can always change the accepted answer if someone comes by later and writes a better answer. Also, welcome to Board and Card Games (and Stack Exchange in general)!

Comment: This is also somewhat covered by the rule that any permanent removed from the battlefield or the stack, if it were to come back, comes back as a completely new instance of the card. (I can't access the rulebook atm to find the exact ruling).